# user is authenticated in profile page(redirected to profile page), but not logged in different pages

Tags: django

I'm using Userena, I set everything that I can register/login/change my profile..etc but as soon as I leave the profile page I'm automatically logged out or seems like never logged in.

seems like there's something wrong in this maybe? 
this is from base.html, I pass that to index html but inside index html, not logged in.

```
  {% load static %}
{% load i18n static %}
{% load url from future %}
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <li><a href="/accounts/signout">Logout</a></li>
     <li><a href="{% url 'add_category' %}">Add a new Category</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="/accounts/signup/">Register Here</a></li>
    <li><a href="/accounts/signin/">Login</a></li>
    {% endif %}
```

I have no idea where to look at, please help

my views.py for index

```
#for front page
def index(request):

    categories = Category.objects.order_by('likes')[:5]
    latest_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    popular_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-views')
    hot_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-score')[:25]

    t = loader.get_template('main/index.html')
    context_dict = {
        'latest_posts' :latest_posts,
        'popular_posts' :popular_posts,
        'hot_posts' :hot_posts,
        'categories':categories
}
    c = Context(context_dict)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: You're probably not passing the `user` key to the template, or using a RequestContext that would do that automatically.

Comment: but the code up there belongs to base.html, are you saying I should add 'user' : user to context_dict and pass that to index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including `{{ user }}` or `{% user.is_authenticated %}` in your template will only work if the `user` is included in the template context. You can either add it explicitly in your view,

```
    context_dict = {
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'popular_posts': popular_posts,
        'hot_posts': hot_posts,
        'categories': categories,
        'user': request.user,
    }
    c = Context(context_dict)
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

or you can use the `render` shortcut, which takes care of loading the template and rendering it for you.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

    categories = Category.objects.order_by('likes')[:5]
    latest_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    popular_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-views')
    hot_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-score')[:25]

    context_dict = {
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'popular_posts': popular_posts,
        'hot_posts': hot_posts,
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context_dict)
```

If you use the render shortcut, you need to make sure that the     `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'`, is included in your [`context_processors`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) setting (it's included in the default generated settings file).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having little bit hard time understanding this, user needs to be authenticated inside base.html no? I have to send user to every page then? and when I use render I don't need to add user? this is my first time doing django project

Comment: it works like a charm, thank you..why is this working for other pages... I just changed index view now it works for add_post page as well which is awesome

Comment: Hey Alasdair, do you know how to edit profile page for userena?

Comment: When you use `render`, the template context includes variables from your context processors (in particular, the `user` from the auth context processor). This avoids the repetition of having to add `user` to the template context in every view.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't have any experiece with userena.

Comment: ok I should use render from now on then, if you have time can you please take alook at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059010/image-scraping-with-beautifulsoup-in-django